# Invalid Login Response when attempting to access an IBM Cognos Analytics

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

we are using cogons 11 and hosted in linux server.When I attempting to access an IBM Cognos Anlaytics using web browser it gives 'Invalid Login Response'. When I start the server it work few times and get slow and suddenly give this error.Previously I tried with changing ping timeout in seconds, inactivity timeout in seconds but it do not work in that way. 
I am using port (portnumber) 9300 and dataset service port number is 9301.

Gateway URL: http://servername:80/bi/v1/disp 
External dispatcher URI :http://servername:portnumber/p2pd/servlet/dispatch 
internal dispatch URI : http://servername:portnumber/p2pd/servlet/dispatch 
Dispatcher URI for external applications: http://servername:portnumber/p2pd/servlet/dispatch 
content manager URIs : http://servername:portnumber/p2pd/servlet

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: What did you see in the log files?


I see that you asked this question here so I'm assuming that the suggested actions were tried but did not change anything.   Could you mention this sort of trouble shooting attempts and their response please.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10737715

Comment: Can you describe the qualities of the linux server (is it a virtual machine?)
How much Ram, disk space, etc?